# VBA, Combine PDFs into one PDF file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine PDF's into one single pdf with the use of vba.
I would like to not use a plug in tool and have tried with acrobat api below.

I have tried something like, but cannot seem to get it to work. I get no error msg but perhaps I am missing parts.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   Sub Combine()


   Dim n As Long, PDFfileName As String

    n = 1
    Do
        n = n + 1
        PDFfileName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "firstpdf" & n & ".pdf")
        If PDFfileName <> "" Then
            'Open the source document that will be added to the destination
            objCAcroPDDocSource.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "pathwithpdfs" & PDFfileName
            If objCAcroPDDocDestination.InsertPages(objCAcroPDDocDestination.GetNumPages - 1, objCAcroPDDocSource, 0, objCAcroPDDocSource.GetNumPages, 0) Then
                MsgBox "Merged " & PDFfileName
            Else
                MsgBox "Error merging " & PDFfileName
            End If
            objCAcroPDDocSource.Close
        End If
    Loop While PDFfileName <> ""


   End Sub
```

new code:

New Code:

```
Sub main()

    Dim arrayFilePaths() As Variant
    Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")

    arrayFilePaths = Array("mypath.pdf", _
                            "mypath2.pdf")

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(0))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    For arrayIndex = 1 To UBound(arrayFilePaths)
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(arrayIndex))
        Debug.Print "SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        numberOfPagesToInsert = sourceDoc.GetNumPages

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
        Debug.Print "PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, arrayFilePaths(0))
        Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

        Set sourceDoc = Nothing
    Next arrayIndex

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no built-in mechanism for doing this in Excel VBA: pretty sure you will need a 3rd party tool/library.

Comment: @TimWilliams ,  it is the code for the acrobat api which does all excel vba to combine pdfs.

Comment: But you say you don't want to use a third-party component.

Comment: fixed the question, I am open to acrobat api if it is the only way.. Dont want to use a random plugin though.

Comment: seems like your second code doesn't specify the path and relies on the current directory being the same as the one where the files are, so it would work sometimes. Issue in the first code seems to be a missing \ in the path: `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\filename.pdf"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You need to have adobe acrobat installed / operational.

I used this resource re method references

https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/iac_api_reference.pdf

> EDIT: Swapping the array for auto generated (mostly, the primary pdf still set by user) list of pathways to pdfs that you want to insert into the primary pdf)

You can use something like below to generate the collection of documents to be inserted into your primary doc. The first file in the `collection` would be the `file` that you are inserting into, same as in first example. Then assign the folder pathway of the folder with the pdf `files` that you would like to see inserted into your primary doc to `inputDirectoryToScanForFile`. The `loop` in this code will add the pathway of every pdf file in that folder to your `collection`. These are the pathways later used in the adobe API calls to insert pdf into your primary.

```
Sub main()

Dim myCol                               As Collection
Dim strFile                             As String
Dim inputDirectoryToScanForFile         As String
Dim primaryFile                         As String

    Set myCol = New Collection

    primaryFile = "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\myPDf.Pdf"

    myCol.Add primaryFile

    inputDirectoryToScanForFile = "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\New Folder\"

    strFile = Dir(inputDirectoryToScanForFile & "*.pdf")

    Do While strFile <> ""
        myCol.Add strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

> Code that takes a primary file and inserts other pdfs into that file:

```
Sub main()

    Dim arrayFilePaths() As Variant
    Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")

    arrayFilePaths = Array("C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\PAGE1.pdf", _
                            "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\PAGE2.pdf", _
                            "C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\PAGE3.pdf")

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(0))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    For arrayIndex = 1 To UBound(arrayFilePaths)
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(arrayIndex))
        Debug.Print "SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        numberOfPagesToInsert = sourceDoc.GetNumPages

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
        Debug.Print "PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, arrayFilePaths(0))
        Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

        Set sourceDoc = Nothing
    Next arrayIndex

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this, i get `DONE` , but where does the final file export too? how do I set this?

Comment: primary doc is the first file path / pdf that you put into your array

Comment: I checked my path in the array, I dont see my second pdf appended to this file. Am I missing something else I have to alter?

Comment: primary doc as the first one in array, the rest in array should be the paths you want to insert into the first array. really should work tbh idk why it wouldn't.

Comment: chack your immediate window, are you getting trues for each step?

Comment: False on each step,  I am using 2 sample pdf files. I checked the first path and nothing appended.
`PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: False
SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: False
PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: False
PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: False`

Comment: do you own adobe acrobat?

Comment: Yes,  adobe acrobat XI pro. It has the 'Combine Files into PDF' ability.

Comment: edit OP with your new code and i will take a look, only thing i can think of is file paths are wrong or are not in array properly. make sure u put .pdf at end that threw me off

Comment: Okay going to add code, and now I added in `.pdf` now I have 
`PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: True
SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: True
PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: False
PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: False`.

Also I accidentally edited your answer, please reject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177689/discussion-between-excelguy-and-learnaswego).

Comment: now I am getting `PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: True
SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: True
PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: True
PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: False` lol. sorry for the spam. but now I have 3 true out of 4.

Comment: Hey looks like your original code works now.. not sure what changed. lol, just going to test some more.

Comment: hey, trying to make `arrayFilePaths` a larger array, what does `(arrayFilePaths(0))` do ? specifically the `0`, Im getting subscript out of range each time I try to make `arrayFilePaths` more dynamic.

Comment: using a collection like in the mini example above to get and store file pathways may be your best bet. in my example arrayFilePaths(0) was storing the pathway of the pdf file that I inserted into. It was my primaryDoc. likely the pathways inside your array are not valid.

Answer (score 3):

This is my understanding of your question:

**Requirements:**

•   Combined a series of pdf files, located in the same folder of the workbook containing the procedure

•   Pdf files names go from `firstpdf1.pdf` to `firstpdfn.pdf` where `n` is the total number of files to be combined

**Let’s review your original code:**

•   All variables should be declared:

```
Dim objCAcroPDDocSource as object, objCAcroPDDocDestination as object
```

•   This line is missing the path separator `"\"`:

```
PDFfileName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "firstpdf" & n & ".pdf")
```

It should be `PDFfileName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "firstpdf" & n & ".pdf")`

•   Therefore this line always returns `""` (no pdf file was found in the `ThisWorkbook.Path`):

`If PDFfileName <> "" Then`

**Additionally:**

•   These lines would have returned:  `Error - 424 Object required` as the objects `objCAcroPDDocSource` and `objCAcroPDDocDestination` were not initialized:

`objCAcroPDDocSource.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "pathwithpdfs" & PDFfileName`

`If objCAcroPDDocDestination.InsertPages(objCAcroPDDocDestination.GetNumPages - 1, objCAcroPDDocSource, 0, objCAcroPDDocSource.GetNumPages, 0) Then`

`objCAcroPDDocSource.Close`

•   The `objCAcroPDDocDestination` was never opened.

**Solutions:**
*These procedures use the Adobe Acrobat Library*

**Adobe Acrobat Library - Early bound**

To create the Vb Reference to the Adobe Library in the VBA Editor menu click `Tools``References`then select the`Adobe Acrobat Library`in the dialog window then press the`OK` button.

```
Sub PDFs_Combine_EarlyBound()
Dim PdfDst As AcroPDDoc, PdfSrc As AcroPDDoc
Dim sPdfComb As String, sPdf As String
Dim b As Byte

    Rem Set Combined Pdf filename - save the combined pdf in a new file in order to preserve original pdfs
    sPdfComb = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Pdf Combined" & Format(Now, " mmdd_hhmm ") & ".pdf"   'change as required

    Rem Open Destination Pdf
    b = 1
    sPdf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "firstpdf" & b & ".pdf"
    Set PdfDst = New AcroPDDoc
    If Not (PdfDst.Open(sPdf)) Then
        MsgBox "Error opening destination pdf:" & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do

        Rem Set & Validate Source Pdf
        b = b + 1
        sPdf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "firstpdf" & b & ".pdf"
        If Dir(sPdf, vbArchive) = vbNullString Then Exit Do

        Rem Open Source Pdf
        Set PdfSrc = New AcroPDDoc
        If Not (PdfSrc.Open(sPdf)) Then
            MsgBox "Error opening source pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
                & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
            GoTo Exit_Sub
        End If

        With PdfDst

            Rem Insert Source Pdf pages
            If Not (.InsertPages(-1 + .GetNumPages, PdfSrc, 0, PdfSrc.GetNumPages, 0)) Then
                MsgBox "Error inserting source pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
                GoTo Exit_Sub
            End If

            Rem Save Combined Pdf
            If Not (.Save(PDSaveFull, sPdfComb)) Then
                MsgBox "Error saving combined pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdfComb & "]" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
                GoTo Exit_Sub
            End If

            PdfSrc.Close
            Set PdfSrc = Nothing

        End With

'        sPdf = Dir(sPdf, vbArchive)
'    Loop While sPdf <> vbNullString
    Loop

    MsgBox "Pdf files combined successfully!", vbExclamation

Exit_Sub:
    PdfDst.Close

   End Sub
```

**Adobe Acrobat Library - Late bound**

No need to create the Vb Reference to the Adobe Library

```
Sub PDFs_Combine_LateBound()
Dim PdfDst As Object, PdfSrc As Object
Dim sPdfComb As String, sPdf As String
Dim b As Byte

    Rem Set Combined Pdf filename - save the combined pdf in a new file in order to preserve original pdfs
    sPdfComb = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Pdf Combined" & Format(Now, " mmdd_hhmm ") & ".pdf"   'change as required

    Rem Open Destination Pdf
    b = 1
    sPdf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "firstpdf" & b & ".pdf"
    Set PdfDst = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    If Not (PdfDst.Open(sPdf)) Then
        MsgBox "Error opening destination pdf:" & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
            & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do

        Rem Set & Validate Source filename
        b = b + 1
        sPdf = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "firstpdf" & b & ".pdf"
        If Dir(sPdf, vbArchive) = vbNullString Then Exit Do

        Rem Open Source filename
        Set PdfSrc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        If Not (PdfSrc.Open(sPdf)) Then
            MsgBox "Error opening source pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
                & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
            GoTo Exit_Sub
        End If

        With PdfDst

            Rem Insert Source filename pages
            If Not (.InsertPages(-1 + .GetNumPages, PdfSrc, 0, PdfSrc.GetNumPages, 0)) Then
                MsgBox "Error inserting source pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdf & "]" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
                GoTo Exit_Sub
            End If

            Rem Save Combined Pdf
            If Not (.Save(1, sPdfComb)) Then
                MsgBox "Error saving combined pdf:" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & "[" & sPdfComb & "]" & vbCrLf _
                    & vbCrLf & vbTab & "Procees will be cancelled!", vbCritical
                GoTo Exit_Sub
            End If

            PdfSrc.Close
            Set PdfSrc = Nothing

        End With

'        sPdf = Dir(sPdf, vbArchive)
'    Loop While sPdf <> vbNullString
    Loop

    MsgBox "Pdf files combined successfully!", vbExclamation

Exit_Sub:
    PdfDst.Close

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I created two pdf's, and merged them to create one pdf using Open Office.  The sub opens LibreDraw, inserts the pdf's as images and exports to pdf.  Must have draw closed to work.

```
    sub MergePDF()

    Dim Doc As Object 'This workbook

    Dim NewWorkBookURL As String

    NewWorkBookURL = "private:factory/sdraw"
 
    Dim noArgs() 'An empty array for the arguments

    Dim Point As New com.sun.star.awt.Point
    Dim Size As New com.sun.star.awt.Size

    Point.x = 0
    Point.y = 0
    'A4
    Size.Width = 21000
    Size.Height = 29700

    Dim Page1 As Object 'Excel sheet
    Dim Page2 As Object 'AutoCAD sheet

    Dim Image1 As Object 'PDF1
    Dim Image2 As Object 'PDF2

    Dim DocPath1 As String
    Dim DocPath2 As String
    Dim DocPath3 As String

    DocPath1 = ConvertToURL("C:\Users\pdf1.pdf")
    DocPath2 = ConvertToURL("C:\Users\pdf2.pdf")
    DocPath3 = ConvertToURL("C:\Users\pdf3.pdf")

    Doc = StarDesktop.LoadComponentFromUrl(NewWorkBookURL, "_blank", 0, noArgs())

    Page1 = Doc.DrawPages(0)
    Page1.Name = "PDF1"

    Page2 = Doc.Drawpages.insertNewByIndex(2)
    Page2.Name = "PDF2"

   'Page 1  
    Image1 = Doc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicObjectShape")
    Image1.GraphicURL = DocPath1
    
    Image1.Size = Size
    Image1.Position = Point
    Page1.add(Image1)

    'Page 2 
    Image2 = Doc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicObjectShape")
    Image2.GraphicURL = DocPath2
    
    Image2.Size = Size
    Image2.Position = Point
    Page2.add(Image2)

    'ExportToPDF

    dim args2(2) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args2(0).Name = "URL"
    args2(0).Value = DocPath3
    args2(1).Name = "FilterName"
    args2(1).Value = "calc_pdf_Export"

    args2(2).Name = "FilterData"
    args2(2).Value = Array(Array("UseLosslessCompression",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Quality",0,90,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ReduceImageResolution",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("MaxImageResolution",0,300,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("UseTaggedPDF",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("SelectPdfVersion",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportNotes",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportBookmarks",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("OpenBookmarkLevels",0,-1,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("UseTransitionEffects",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("IsSkipEmptyPages",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("IsAddStream",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("FormsType",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportFormFields",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("HideViewerToolbar",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("HideViewerMenubar",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("HideViewerWindowControls",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ResizeWindowToInitialPage",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("CenterWindow",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("OpenInFullScreenMode",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("DisplayPDFDocumentTitle",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("InitialView",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Magnification",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Zoom",0,100,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PageLayout",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("FirstPageOnLeft",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("InitialPage",0,1,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Printing",0,2,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Changes",0,4,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("EnableCopyingOfContent",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("EnableTextAccessForAccessibilityTools",0,true,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportLinksRelativeFsys",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PDFViewSelection",0,0,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ConvertOOoTargetToPDFTarget",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("ExportBookmarksToPDFDestination",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("_OkButtonString",0,"",com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("EncryptFile",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("DocumentOpenPassword",0,"",com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("RestrictPermissions",0,false,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("PermissionPassword",0,"",com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE),Array("Selection",0,,com.sun.star.beans.PropertyState.DIRECT_VALUE))

    Doc.storeToURL(DocPath3,args2())


    msgbox "Done"

    End sub
```

No Adobe required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a exact soluation for your problem, however, I had a similar one, namely that I wanted to add fields to a pdf from VBA.

I can tell you that Adobe has a JavaScript API which you can control through vba.

Here is the link to the API
https://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html

And this is a part of the code I used in VBA to control fields in the PDFs.

```
Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
app.Show
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'from AFormAPI
AVDoc.Open(pathsdf, "")

Ex = "Put your JavaScript Code here"

AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript Ex
```

You should probably look at the insertPages method in the API.

What is als possible is using the build in reference from VBA to Acrobat. However, I found it very limited and I did not work with it. There are only a few objects available, here are some examples:

```
Dim AcroApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim objAcroAVDoc As New Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim objAcroPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim objAcroPDPage As Acrobat.AcroPDPage
Dim annot As Acrobat.AcroPDAnnot
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code i got from stack overflow this will list all sub folders in a folder.

```
Sub FolderNames()
'Update 20141027
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Choose the folder"
.Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
'Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear
xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Path", "Dir", "Name", "Date Created",            "Date Last Modified")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder1 = fso.GetFolder(xPath)
getSubFolder folder1
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Interior.Color = 65535
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object)
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim subfld As Object
Dim xRow As Long
For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(SubFolder.Path, Left(SubFolder.Path,       InStrRev(SubFolder.Path, "\")), SubFolder.Name, SubFolder.DateCreated, SubFolder.DateLastModified)
Next SubFolder
For Each subfld In prntfld.SubFolders
getSubFolder subfld
Next subfld
End Sub
```

This Code will Combine all PDF files in sub-folder and stores the output in chosen destination folder

```
Sub Merger()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim k As Integer
Dim st As String
Dim na As String
Dim dest As String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
.Title = "Choose the Destination folder"
.Show
End With
dest = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"


k = sh.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To k
st = sh.Cells(i, 1).Value
na = sh.Cells(i, 3).Value
Call Main(st, na, dest)
Next

 MsgBox "The resulting files are created" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbInformation, "Done"

End Sub

Sub Main(ByVal st As String, ByVal na As String, dest As String)

Dim DestFile As String
DestFile = "" & dest & na & ".pdf" ' <-- change TO Your Required Desitination

Dim MyPath As String, MyFiles As String
Dim a() As String, i As Long, f As String
Dim R As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim n As Long



 ' Choose the folder or just replace that part by: MyPath = Range("E3")
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
     '.InitialFileName = "C:\Temp\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    'If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
    MyPath = st
    DoEvents
End With

  ' Populate the array a() by PDF file names
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
ReDim a(1 To 2 ^ 14)

f = Dir(MyPath & "*")
While Len(f)
    If StrComp(f, DestFile, vbTextCompare) Then
        i = i + 1
        a(i) = f
        'a().Sort
    End If
    f = Dir()
Wend
```

'SORTING--------------------------------------------------------

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

' put the array values on the worksheet
Set R = ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1, 1)
R = Application.Transpose(a)

' sort the range
R.Sort key1:=R, order1:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False

' load the worksheet values back into the array
For n = 1 To R.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    a(n) = R(n, 1)
Next n

If i Then
    ReDim Preserve a(1 To i)
    MyFiles = Join(a, ",")
    Application.StatusBar = "Merging, please wait ..."
    Call MergePDFs(MyPath, MyFiles, DestFile)
    Application.StatusBar = False
Else
    MsgBox "No PDF files found in" & vbLf & MyPath, vbExclamation, "Canceled"
End If

End Sub
```

'ZVI:2013-08-27 http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47310-Need-code-to-merge-PDF-files-in-a-folder-using-adobe-acrobat-X
' Reference required: VBE - Tools - References - Acrobat

```
Sub MergePDFs(MyPath As String, MyFiles As String, Optional DestFile As String)
Dim a As Variant, i As Long, n As Long, ni As Long, p As String
Dim AcroApp As New Acrobat.AcroApp, PartDocs() As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
If Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then p = MyPath Else p = MyPath & "\"
a = Split(MyFiles, ",")
ReDim PartDocs(0 To UBound(a))

On Error GoTo exit_
If Len(Dir(DestFile)) Then Kill p & DestFile
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    ' Check PDF file presence
    If Dir(p & Trim(a(i))) = "" Then
        MsgBox "File not found" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
        Exit For
    End If
    ' Open PDF document
    Set PartDocs(i) = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    PartDocs(i).Open p & Trim(a(i))
    If i Then
        ' Merge PDF to PartDocs(0) document
        ni = PartDocs(i).GetNumPages()
        If Not PartDocs(0).InsertPages(n - 1, PartDocs(i), 0, ni, True) Then
            MsgBox "Cannot insert pages of" & vbLf & p & a(i), vbExclamation, "Canceled"
        End If
        ' Calc the number of pages in the merged document
        n = n + ni
        ' Release the memory
        PartDocs(i).Close
        Set PartDocs(i) = Nothing
    Else
        ' Calc the number of pages in PartDocs(0) document
        n = PartDocs(0).GetNumPages()
    End If
Next

If i > UBound(a) Then
    ' Save the merged document to DestFile
    If Not PartDocs(0).Save(PDSaveFull, DestFile) Then
        MsgBox "Cannot save the resulting document" & vbLf & p & DestFile,    vbExclamation, "Canceled"
    End If
End If
 exit_:

' Inform about error/success
If Err Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error #" & Err.Number
ElseIf i > UBound(a) Then
    'MsgBox "The resulting file is created:" & vbLf & p & DestFile, vbInformation, "Done"
End If

' Release the memory
If Not PartDocs(0) Is Nothing Then PartDocs(0).Close
Set PartDocs(0) = Nothing

' Quit Acrobat application
AcroApp.Exit
Set AcroApp = Nothing

End Sub
```