# VBA Excel: print multiple pages to one pdf

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have an attendance list for a training to which I copy names to. I have a macro that does sorting and layout, and then prints an actual attendance list for a range of dates which is provided e.g. 2 weeks, with a print command after every new date.

However, instead of printing, I would like to save all the different sheets into 1 pdf which I can mail to the trainer.
But either with the print to file or export command, I always get one single pdf for every single attendance list.
Anyone sees a solution to save e.g. 15 lists into 1 pdf?

Comment: Perhaps useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389983/vba-combine-pdfs-into-one-pdf-file

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to print 15 pdf's first then to save them all into 1 file. I'm looking for a way to export/print them to pdf all at once.