# Merging PDF's using Excel 2016 VBA

Tags: vba, pdf

ive found this piece of vba code that will help me merge pdf files in a folder into a single pdf - my vba errors out at the MergePDFs function and detailed out the following error:

> wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Any idea how to make this work??

```
Sub Combine_PDFs()
    Dim strPDFs(0 To 1) As String
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean
    Dim FolderPath As String

    FolderPath = "C:\Users\ITG-0720\OneDrive - INSTITUTO TECNOLOGICO DO GAS\ITG\DMM\Certificados"

    strPDFs(0) = FolderPath & "\" & Sheets("Análise CC").Range("D9")
    strPDFs(1) = FolderPath & "\" & Sheets("Análise CC").Range("O4")

    bSuccess = MergePDFs(strPDFs, FolderPath & "\" & Sheets("Análise CC").Range("O4"))

    If bSuccess = False Then MsgBox "Failed to combine all PDFs", vbCritical, "Failed to Merge PDFs"
End Sub
```

Comment: How is `MergePDFs` defined? That is not a built in function, and you did not include it in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA, Combine PDFs into one PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389983/vba-combine-pdfs-into-one-pdf-file)