# Combine PDFs into one PDF file using Access VBA issue

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently using this code to merger my Access reports that are printed out to .pdf. It has been working fine until recently and i am not sure why it is not merging my .pdf files. Could someone look at it and tell me what is wrong. My References is set to Adobe Acrobat 10.0 Type Library. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim Encl2, Encl2FN, Encl2Path, Encl3, Encl3FN, Encl3Path, Encl4, Encl4FN, Encl4Path As String
Dim RPath, TempPath, TempPathEncl2, TempPathEncl3, TempPathEncl4 As String
Dim UserPth, strfile, strFilePath As String
Dim arrayFilePaths() As Variant
Dim app As Acrobat.CAcroApp
Dim primaryDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim SourceDoc As Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc
Dim OK
Dim arrayIndex
Dim numberOfPagesToInsert As String
Dim numPages As Integer

Encl2 = "rpt_Delegation_Enclosure2"
Encl3 = "rpt_Delegation_Enclosure3"
Encl4 = "rpt_Delegation_Enclosure4"

Encl2FN = "Enclosure2" & ".pdf"
Encl3FN = "Enclosure3" & ".pdf"
Encl4FN = "Enclosure4" & ".pdf"

UserPth = Environ("USERPROFILE")
TempPathEncl2 = UserPth & "\Desktop\" & Encl2FN
TempPathEncl3 = UserPth & "\Desktop\" & Encl3FN
TempPathEncl4 = UserPth & "\Desktop\" & Encl4FN
strfile = "SourceRpt" & ".pdf"
strFilePath = UserPth & "\Desktop\" & strFile

RPath = strFilePath

    Set app = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

    arrayFilePaths = Array(RPath, TempPathEncl2, TempPathEncl3, TempPathEncl4)

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(0))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK
            
    For arrayIndex = 1 To UBound(arrayFilePaths)
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set SourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = SourceDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(arrayIndex))
        Debug.Print "SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        numberOfPagesToInsert = SourceDoc.GetNumPages

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, SourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
        Debug.Print "PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, arrayFilePaths(0))
        Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK
        
        Set SourceDoc = Nothing
    Next arrayIndex

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run that code?

Comment: So it is suppose to open the source file from the array. then Insert each file after that while doing each file it is suppose to save the file each time during the loop. upon further test it is not opening the source file. However it is also not giving me any error messages. which is strange.

Comment: What's the `Debug.Print` output?

Comment: using it to display the results if the file is opened : PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: False 
that is the result from the first Debug.Print command.

Comment: SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: True
PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: False
PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: False

Comment: that is the ouput of the Debug.Print for the next three that are in the loop

Comment: `primaryDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(0))` is trying to open `RPath`, which is just your desktop folder, not an actual file

Comment: I updated my code to the correct information for it to acctually open a file and still it is not performing correctly. giving me the same `debug.print` messages above.

Comment: thank you for catching that. Lol one problem down.

Comment: Maybe check your file paths using `Dir()` to make certain they're all pointing to existing files

Comment: sorry had a meeting. So I did a `Dir()` on the paths and they located them all. I am concerned about the `Debug.Print` Output of `PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: False` is that saying it is not saving the file?

Comment: Yes that is the reference i used and it worked fine until recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked fine for me

Adapted from: [VBA, Combine PDFs into one PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389983/vba-combine-pdfs-into-one-pdf-file)

```vb
Sub main()

    Const PDSaveFull = 1
    Dim arrayFilePaths() As Variant, OK, arrayIndex As Long
    Dim primaryDoc, app, numPages, numberOfPagesToInsert, sourceDoc
    
    Set app = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")

    arrayFilePaths = Array("C:\Tester\PDF_Sheet1.pdf", _
                            "C:\Tester\PDF_Sheet2.pdf", _
                            "C:\Tester\PDF_Sheet3.pdf")

    Set primaryDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
    OK = primaryDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(0))
    Debug.Print "PRIMARY DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

    For arrayIndex = 1 To UBound(arrayFilePaths)
        numPages = primaryDoc.GetNumPages() - 1

        Set sourceDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
        OK = sourceDoc.Open(arrayFilePaths(arrayIndex))
        Debug.Print "SOURCE DOC OPENED & PDDOC SET: " & OK

        numberOfPagesToInsert = sourceDoc.GetNumPages

        OK = primaryDoc.InsertPages(numPages, sourceDoc, 0, numberOfPagesToInsert, False)
        Debug.Print "PAGES INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY: " & OK

        OK = primaryDoc.Save(PDSaveFull, arrayFilePaths(0))
        Debug.Print "PRIMARYDOC SAVED PROPERLY: " & OK

        Set sourceDoc = Nothing
    Next arrayIndex

    Set primaryDoc = Nothing
    app.Exit
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "DONE"
End Sub
```