# Acrobat Reader 4 - VBA references

Tags: excel, vba, adobe

I have Acrobat Reader 4 installed on my PC and I want to merge two pdf's using Excel VBA. Are there app objects available for Acrobat Reader 4. I am using Excel 2007.

Comment: Are you able to manually merge pdf files in Acrobat Reader? I  know that this is possible only in Adobe Acrobat Pro...

Comment: I though so.  It is possible to merge pdf's using LibreOffice; just need to work out how to control it in a program. Thanks

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389983/vba-combine-pdfs-into-one-pdf-file), plese.